# Testing Role Hierarchy

Tags: unit-test

In a recent Project we kinda re-modeled the **Role -Hierarchy** in an existing Org. A lot of Sales users were moved from reporting to one manager to other.
In **UAT** it was very easy to check if the same set of Users are indeed rolling up to the manager via Reports. I created Generic reports and all I had to do was to log in as the Manger go to Reports and check the following:

1. My Team's Opportunities
2. My Team's Leads and
3. My Team's Accounts.

When you group this report by **Owner** and **Hide Details**, I could very quickly conclude whether the Dev Team have done the **User-To-Manager-Mapping** correctly. However it gets tricky to create a Report for **My Teams Cases**.

If a manager needs to log in to check `Cases` that are owned **ONLY** by people who are reporting to him how can this be achieved instead of adding a Filter and adding all the subordinate's names manually? It's time consuming and there are more than 500 Users with Managerial-Role in the Org, which means to say I would have to create 500 diff reports to check if the Roll-Up is happening appropriately. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prepare the report with the show criteria **"My role-based team's cases"**

This way, if manager logs in to salesforce and runs this report, he will see only his subordinates' records who are reporting to him.

Also, if a subordinate runs this report he will see only his records.

The data visibility will respect role-hierarchy.

[image: Reporting]